# On what countries in the Americas the US has (or hasn't) imposed travel restrictions related to Covid-19?

Tags: donald-trump, covid-19, borders, south-america, north-america

Interesting [news](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/20/coronavirus-trump-considering-imposing-a-travel-ban-on-brazil.html?recirc=taboolainternal) that the US is (only now) considering a travel ban on Brazil. I think the borders with Canada and Mexico were closed [sooner](https://news.yahoo.com/canada-us-border-closure-extended-until-june-21-160547308.html).

So, on what countries in the Americas did the US impose travel restrictions related to Covid-19? I.e. is there a timeline of US-imposed travel restrictions; better still, is there a timeline that correlates those decisions with the number cases reported in those countries at the time?

Comment: To be fair, it is much harder to police a land border like Mexico or Canada (where I live) than it is to screen airline passengers aggressively when they arrive or even before they board their planes.  So a timeline comparing the number of Canadian cases to Brazilian cases doesn't really say much.  And closing the border wasn't necessarily a bad call.  Truth be told, given how the US epidemic is progressing, Canadians are probably not that thrilled at the border being reopened to non-essential/non-commercial travelers.  Except for Ontario and Quebec, we are seeing nowhere near US numbers.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: fair point regarding the land borders. But there are quite a  few countries in the Americas that don't have a land border with the US. Some also had bad (ot at least badly managed) outbreaks of Covid-19, e.g. Ecuador.

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica: That could easily be because except for certain cities in Ontario & Quebec, Canada doesn't HAVE US numbers.  Indeed, even the US numbers are mostly coming from large, congested urban areas.  Which only makes sense:  it's much easier to maintain social distancing &c if you live in rural Nevada or Manitoba, than if you live in Manhattan or Montreal.

Comment: @jamesqf more complicated than that.  first, I wouldn't be surprised if Canada was *more* urbanized than the US.  remember, the vast majority of our population lives close to the 49th, with the exception of Edmonton, again a big city.  Second, not all cities have suffered equally.  Vancouver is much less hit per capita than Montreal or Toronto, and Seattle stabilized way sooner than NYC.  Might be colder weather drives people indoors and in public transport over cycling/walking.  Anyway, my point stands that pausing *discretionary* land travel to/from the US is not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 22 May, apart from the mutual decisions to close the land borders with Canada and Mexico to non-essential travel, the US has imposed no restrictions on travelers coming from the Americas.

It is worth noting that, even though the land borders may be closed, flights between the US, Canada and Mexico are continuing.

Comment: I guess they didn't need to, to some extent since countries like Argentina or Colombia have [suspended all flights anyway](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-health-coronavirus-latam-airlines/colombia-follows-argentina-in-banning-all-international-flights-through-august-31-idUSKBN22W2T8). Likewise for Guatemala and Ecuador: https://news.delta.com/update-latin-america-service-suspension-extends-bogota-and-cartagena-colombia

Comment: The US has actually imposed restrictions on Brazil starting on May 29 [now](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/24/trump-suspends-travel-from-brazil-as-coronavirus-pandemic-worsens-in-south-america.html). As with previous bans on travel from the EU, China etc., it doesn't apply to US citizens, permanent residents etc.